# Cost of NSObject casting in particular UIView casting in iOS by using #define

Tags: objective-c, uiview, casting, uiviewcontroller, ios5

I tend to do everything with Interface Builder and IBOutlet, so that when I want to modify user interface I use to declare a variable in UIViewController, for example:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet MyView *myView;
```

connect it trough Interface Builder and recall in my code using the outlet, then I can access all the other outlet in myView:

```
UILabel *label = myView.theLabel;
```

Considering that MyView is very often my main view, I could also do:

```
UILabel *label = (MyView*)self.view.theLabel;
```

the syntax is quite long, but this allow me to declare less variable in the .h file and (in my opinion) keep code cleaner, for example with a macro this could become:

```
#define MV (MyView*)self.view

UILabel *label = MV.theLabel;
```

which I found to be much more nice to read and maintain.
The point is that I would always do a casting, using iOS 5 what's the cost in terms of performance ? Considering the UIKit is already a layer on top of something else is UIView object casting somewhat different or more expensive ?
Does the compiler do some kind of optimizations especially with the new arc compiler ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casting happens at compile time, and as such has ***absolutely no runtime cost***.

**Sidebar:** This way of using defines still strikes me as a bit iffy, but hey, if it works for you…

**Edit:** The issue you are describing is a result of conflating the purposes of the classes in your code: MyView should not need to have any outlets to speak of; keeping track of all of that jazz is the job of the view controller.

In other words; you probably don't want `self.view.label`; but rather `self.relevantNameForTheLabel`.

Comment: Eh eh...thanks, I am always interested in other opinions, especially when I am new to a programming language. Could you explain other downside of this approach ? Maybe in your answer.

Comment: @Leonardo: Edited as best I could without seeing more of your code.

Comment: thanks, for pointing out an interesting aspect that I am going to investigate.